# Effect of the temperature dependence of $\Delta H_{vap}$ on the vapor pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, evaporation, liquid-state

I am aware that the enthalpy of vaporization of a fluid ,$\Delta H_{vap}$ is temperature dependent since it must be equal to zero at the critical temperature of said fluid, $T_c$ (although this is mainly modeled via material dependent empirical equations). However I am trying to work out how this temperature dependence is factored into the equation for the vapor pressure as a function of temperature:

\begin{equation}
\frac{dlnp}{dT} = \frac{\Delta H_{vap}}{RT^2}
\end{equation}

Where $R$ is the ideal gas constant. If we insert a temperature dependence of $\Delta H_{vap}$ such as:

\begin{equation}
\Delta H_{vap} (T) = \Delta H_{vap} (1-T/T_c)
\end{equation}

We would get the evaporation rate of liquid increasing at a greater rate with temperature than previously expected. However, if one examines the vapor pressure data for a material such as Al (https://www.iap.tuwien.ac.at/www/surface/vapor_pressure), fitting the prior equation to the data here does not agree with the data fully.

My question is, for the case of vapor pressure, does the temperature dependence of the enthalpy of vaporization need to be considered when working over a large temperature range? (for example, it is considered in some literature I have seen, for example: https://engineering.purdue.edu/NanoLab/PDF/2002Non-Equilibrium%20Phase%20Change%20in%20Metal%20Induced%20by%20Nanosecond.pdf). If it should be considered, why does the given vapor pressure data not agree with this? Is it due to how the data is extracted, perhaps from a empirical equation?

Comment: In that paper, where is the content you’re referring to?

Comment: In getting $Delta H_{vap} $ as a function of T, you need to use Hess' law, taking into account non-ideal gas effects for the vapor and liquid.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Eqn 2 in the paper

Comment: Why do you say that equation shows a temperature dependence of enthalpy? It shows $H_{lv}$ multiplied by $T-T_b$, not $H_{lv}$ as a function of $T-T_b$.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Yes, but I interpreted this as an effective temperature dependence of the enthalpy since the temperature dependence is similar to the temperature dependence of the enthalpy of vaporization typically assigned in empirical equations (see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S037838121630509X). However, I'm unsure why this paper uses $T_b$ in this case, so I could be misinterpreting this.

Comment: @Chemomechanics If I am misinterpreting this equation, why is it that the temperature dependence of the enthalpy of vaporization is not explicitly accounted for in the vapor pressure function (Clausius Clapeyron Equation). Particularly when working over a large temperature range where the enthalpy of vaporization does change and thus greatly affects the value of the exponential.

Comment: People like simpler equations if they maintain suitable accuracy. Idealizing the enthalpy of vaporization as a constant is one example. There's nothing stopping you from incorporating the temperature dependence if you wish!

Comment: Thank you for the link to the Alibakhshi paper—that's a nice compilation of references on the topic.